# centralize PHP code and MySQL data

Tags: php, mysql

I currently have a dedicated server and I'm looking to set up a MySQL database, PHP query code and images directory that can be used by multiple sites. A majority of the sites will be hosted on the same machine, but some will not. My simple way of thinking is that this is possible similar to how Roundcube's code and database is centralized.

Looking for some expert input and direction on whether or not it is this simple or if there is a better way of accomplishing this.

Comment: How does your project relate to RoundCube? Do you speak of the email client, don't you?

Comment: @LorenzMeyer Roundcube was just an example of how similar of scenario I thought my situation would be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, you could two a couple of things to improve your situation:

- store your images in just one place, and **use that place as a CDN** to deliver contents across your sites;

About your code:

- if it's possible, **use packages** in order to create a single package for all the "common" code;
- use this package on every site that needs that code, as a simple **dependency**. Tools like *[Composer](https://getcomposer.org/)* are great to handle dependency management;

No big problems with MySQL databases unless you have big traffic numbers. In that case, you should study MySQL scaling. But first of all, focus on PHP and common assets (like images).

EDIT:

- be sure to set appropriate permissions for the external sites, of course;
- using packages for your dependencies will be very useful also for sites placed outside the dedicated server;